# Can anyone tell me what the regex would look like for a date format that cannot be older than today?

Tags: regex, date

What would a regex look like for a date format that cannot be older than today?

Comment: You say “date format,” but I imagine you mean timestamp, right? You want a regex that will match only timestamps from today forward? If that's the case, what format are you hoping the timestamp will be in? If not, what are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

[You can't do that.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26d138a1-05ca-4cbe-9321-aa3d27a4780d/regex-for-todays-date-and-above?forum=regexp)

Regular expressions have no understanding of value computing, they only understand patterns. You can't explain "give me today's date" as a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you meant a format expression.
On the Linux shell:

```
date +%Y%m%d --date="0 days ago"
```